# How can I declare two variables in #begin in convo file in botium

Tags: automation, chatbot

I want to declare two variable for later use in #begin step.
e.g. name | john and number | $random(10)

how can write it in #begin step if I want to initialise above two variables in text convo file in botium

Answer (score 0):

Use the **SET_SCRIPTING_MEMORY** logic hook to initialize variables (see [here](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48660497/Integrated+Logic+Hooks))

```
#begin
SET_SCRIPTING_MEMORY name|john
SET_SCRIPTING_MEMORY number|$random(10)

#me
i am $name and this is my $number

#bot
...
```